# Membership and search criteria

Tags: plugins, membership, plugin-members

I am having trouble finding the best method i which to achieve what i need from my site. I have been playing with some plugins to no avail but basically i need to achieve the below, do we think this is too niche and should be done with custom coding?

- The ability to create multiple different accounts in which there would be 2 different registration
  forms
- uploading pictures for their profile
- Adding eCommerce pricing based on criteria for one of the account types
- Including postal or zip codes
- the ability to search and filter based on variables including "with X miles of" postal/zip code /
  nationwide

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess your question will get closed as it's not  necessarily Wordpress specific and quite opinion based. Why do you want to do this in Wordpress? Have you looked at more data-driven CMS's like Django, or other PHP frameworks?

Comment: Thanks mozbz,
I am pretty new to this so i am not entirely familiar with Wordpress but the limited exposure i had has allowed me to do some but not all of the elements. I will look at your suggestions and see if i can do what i want with them